# Bad bucket URL in CKeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ckeditor, paperclip

I'm using CKeditor and Paperclip.

Upload files is working but the URL in CKeditor is not the good one.

In fact, Ckeditor uses "http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/ckeditor_assets/pictures/12/content_image.jpg"

But the good file path is "http://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/ckeditor_assets/pictures/12/content_image.jpg"

How can i resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my problem with: `:s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'`

Comment: Nice, can I ask where you put that?

Comment: I solved with `url: ":s3_domain_url"` on the ckeditor assets models